# What is the $4\times 2\times 2$ matrix $\sigma_{A \dot B}^{\mu}$ explicitly?

Tags: representation-theory, spinors, clifford-algebra

In [Tales of 1001 Gluons](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.05318) by Stefan Weinzierl, in the end of page 36, (163), $\sigma_{A \dot B}^{\mu} = (1, -\sigma_x, -\sigma_y, -\sigma_z)$. It seems that $\sigma_{A \dot B}^{\mu} = (1, -\sigma_x, -\sigma_y, -\sigma_z)$ is a two by four matrix. Why it is said that $\sigma_{A \dot B}^{\mu} = (1, -\sigma_x, -\sigma_y, -\sigma_z)$ is 4-dimensional? What is matrix $\sigma_{A \dot B}^{\mu}$ explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each matrix $\sigma^{\mu}$, for $\mu = 0,1,2,3$, is a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

This set of four $2 \times 2$ matrices is called the four-dimensional sigma-matrices because they appear in the algebra involving spinors in four space-time dimensions. It does not mean that they are $4 \times 4$ matrices.