# Raising and lowering indices: how to compute $\sigma_{\mu}$ when we know $\sigma^{\mu}$

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I have a question about raising and lowering indices. How to compute $\sigma_{\mu}$ when we know $\sigma^{\mu}$? Here 
\begin{align}
\sigma^{\mu} = \left( \begin{matrix}
\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right),
\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right),
\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{matrix} \right),
\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right)
\end{matrix} \right).
\end{align}

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/341500/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply multiply the "vector" $\sigma^{\mu}$ by the matrix given by the metric tensor:

$$\rm diag\left(\pm 1, \mp 1, \mp 1, \mp 1\right)$$

Which ultimately means putting a $-1$ in front of the time component, or putting $-1$s in front of the space components.  Whether you choose the plus or minus is convention chosen by the problem, but particle physicists typically choose the plus in the time component, while general relativists choose the opposite convention, because these choices give them various simplifications in their algebra.

Comment: thank you very much. Are there some references which explain how to do such computations in general?

Comment: @JianrongLi any book that discusses tensors, especially in a physics context will do so.  The general idea is that, given a metric tensor $g_{ab}$, and it's inverse matrix $g^{ab}$, you have, by convention: $v_{a} = g_{ab}v^{b}$ and $v^{a} = g^{ab}v_{b}$, where Einstein summation convention is used.